# How can I call a function once the final image from a dynamic array is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image

I am trying to append the image elements using a different function than the one which creates them. The reason for doing this would be to implement a loading gif and also have smoother loading of images.

PHP

```
$dir = "images/";
$dh = opendir($dir);
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
$files[] = $filename;


}
foreach ($files as $key=>&$value) {
if (strlen($value) < 3) {
    unset($files[$key]);
}

}
foreach($files as $key => $value) { 
if($value == "") { 
unset($array[$key]); 
} 
} 
$sorted_array = array_values($files);  
uasort ( $sorted_array , function ($a, $b) {
        return strnatcmp($a,$b); // or other function/code
    }

);
$filecount = count($sorted_array);
print_r($sorted_array);
```

javascript

```
 var photos=[];
 var image;
 function map(id){
var name=<?php echo json_encode($sorted_array);?>;
var elements=<?php echo $filecount?>;
for(i=0;i<elements;i++){
    photos[i]=new Array("images/"+name[i]);
    image=new Image();
    image.setAttribute("class","container");
    image.setAttribute("id",photos[i]);
    image.src=photos[i];
    document.getElementById(id).appendChild(image);
    }
    alert(elements);
    return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an `onload` event handler to all the images. Count how many images still need to load, if it reaches `0` you're good to go.

`images.addEventListener` or `images.attachEvent` (for InternetExploder)

Comment: Might as well use `.onload` - it's not like you'd overwrite a past event or anything

Comment: Yea in this instance `.onload` is fine. But, if you're gonna use a JavaScript framework, this what it'll do anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Image.onload` event handler to find out when an image loaded the resource given in `src`. If you have multiple images, you might want to implement a counter (holding the total number of images you want to load) and decrementing that counter in each Image's onload.

Answer (score 0):

I had prepared 3 images with different sizes (to have them being loaded asynchronously).

They are ~18 Kb, ~70 Kb and ~200 Kb. You can use them (provided at the end of the topic).

**UPDATED CODE:**

Let's name this code `index.html` and save it to file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {

        // Define images    
        var photos = [
            {url:'./img1.jpg', loaded:false},
            {url:'./img2.jpg', loaded:false},
            {url:'./img3.jpg', loaded:false},
            {url:'./img1.jpg', loaded:false},
            {url:'./img2.jpg', loaded:false},
            {url:'./img3.jpg', loaded:false},
            {url:'./img2.jpg', loaded:false}
        ],
        photos_DOM_Elements = [],
        photosLoaded = 0;// Loaded images counter
        container = document.getElementById('div');// Images container

        /**
        * Each image should have event listener for `onLoad` event...
        */
        photos.forEach(function (photo, photoInd) {
            var currentImage = document.createElement('img');

            currentImage.src = photo.url;
            photos_DOM_Elements.push(currentImage);

            // ...and this event should check whether it was the last image that haven't been loaded
            currentImage.addEventListener('load', function (evt) {
                photosLoaded++;

                if (photos.length === photosLoaded) {
                    alert('Loaded');

                    // Move images to a visible container
                    photos_DOM_Elements.forEach(function (DOM_Elem) {
                        container.appendChild(DOM_Elem);
                    });
                }
            });
        });

    });
    </script>
</head><body>
    <div id="div"></div>
</body></html>
```

Save as `img1.jpg`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCKzG.jpg
Save as `img2.jpg`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnU3c.jpg
Save as `img3.jpg`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUaYr.jpg

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail in my question. Your code works great but doesn't solve the issue I'm facing. What I am trying to do is once the images are all loaded then have a separate function append them to a div or change a specific attribute to make them visible. For example lets say the images get loaded onclick and are dynamic so specific names are not available. How would I append all of those outside of the function or is there a better route and if so what is it.

Comment: Ah, got it! Please look again at my code - I've updated it:
- you don't need to append images to container while all of them are loaded

Comment: *while = until, sorry for my english

Comment: let me update the code. I'm having trouble working what you are suggesting into a dynamic array.